# Main not defined package python issue

Tags: ros, python

My apologies but I've run out of ideas. I'm very new to python and stuck trying to execute the following code from this [tutorial](https://admin.insights.ubuntu.com/2018/03/09/your-first-robot-the-driver-4-5/?_ga=2.86327889.810740371.1522598579-83214094.1519979733):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Set the GPIO modes
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

_FREQUENCY = 20


def _clip(value, minimum, maximum):
    # """Ensure value is between minimum and maximum."""

    if value < minimum:
        return minimum
    elif value > maximum:
        return maximum
    return value

class Motor:
    def __init__(self, forward_pin, backward_pin):
        self._forward_pin = forward_pin
        self._backward_pin = backward_pin

        GPIO.setup(forward_pin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(backward_pin, GPIO.OUT)

        self._forward_pwm = GPIO.PWM(forward_pin, _FREQUENCY)
        self._backward_pwm = GPIO.PWM(backward_pin, _FREQUENCY)

    def move(self, speed_percent):
        speed = _clip(abs(speed_percent), 0, 100)

        # Positive speeds move wheels forward, negative speeds 
        # move wheels backward
        if speed_percent < 0:
            self._backward_pwm.start(speed)
            self._forward_pwm.start(0)
        else:
            self._forward_pwm.start(speed)
            self._backward_pwm.start(0)

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('driver')

        self._last_received = rospy.get_time()
        self._timeout = rospy.get_param('~timeout', 2)
        self._rate = rospy.get_param('~rate', 10)
        self._max_speed = rospy.get_param('~max_speed', 0.5)
        self._wheel_base = rospy.get_param('~wheel_base', 0.091)

        # Assign pins to motors. These may be distributed
        # differently depending on how you've built your robot
        self._left_motor = Motor(13, 15)
        self._right_motor = Motor(36, 32)
        self._left_speed_percent = 0
        self._right_speed_percent = 0

        # Setup subscriber for velocity twist message
        rospy.Subscriber(
            'cmd_vel', Twist, self.velocity_received_callback)

    def velocity_received_callback(self, message):
        # """Handle new velocity command message."""

        self._last_received = rospy.get_time()

        # Extract linear and angular velocities from the message
        linear = message.linear.x
        angular = message.angular.z

        # Calculate wheel speeds in m/s
        left_speed = linear - angular*self._wheel_base/2
        right_speed = linear + angular*self._wheel_base/2

        # Ideally we'd now use the desired wheel speeds along
        # with data from wheel speed sensors to come up with the
        # power we need to apply to the wheels, but we don't have
        # wheel speed sensors. Instead, we'll simply convert m/s
        # into percent of maximum wheel speed, which gives us a
        # duty cycle that we can apply to each motor.
        self._left_speed_percent = (100 * left_speed/self._max_speed)
        self._right_speed_percent = (100 * right_speed/self._max_speed)

    def run(self):
        # """The control loop of the driver."""

        rate = rospy.Rate(self._rate)

        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            # If we haven't received new commands for a while, we
            # may have lost contact with the commander-- stop
            # moving
            delay = rospy.get_time() - self._last_received
            if delay < self._timeout:
                self._left_motor.move(self._left_speed_percent)
                self._right_motor.move(self._right_speed_percent)
            else:
                self._left_motor.move(0)
                self._right_motor.move(0)

            rate.sleep()

    def main():
        driver = Driver()

        # Run driver. This will block
        driver.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get get the following error:

```
(classic)adeoduye@localhost:~/catkin_ws$ rosrun simple_robot_navigation driver_node_controller
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/adeoduye/catkin_ws/src/simple_robot_navigation/src/driver_node_controller", line 117, in <module>
        main()
    NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

BTW, it's ROS code which I have implemented in my custom ***catkin_ws/src/simple_robot_navigation*** package. I suspect it's a python issue but I very new at python and not sure how to fix it.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there are some indentation error in the tutorial.

In the example code, the function `main` is defined as a function of the class `Driver`. However, as the actual code of `main` goes, it creates an instance of the class `Driver` and run it. So I think the function definition should be at the same indentation level as the class definition. What you need to do is to remove the indentation of the function definition of `main`. That is, remove four white spaces such that the function definition would be

```
def main():
    driver = Driver()
    driver.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```